# How to have a sum() with a where clause

Tags: php, sql

I currently have:

```html
// connect for other mins
$sql = "SELECT sum(mins) FROM completed_activity WHERE member_id = '$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]' AND exercise != 'Personal Training' AND date >= '$mon'";
```

But, when the date is not within the where clause, nothing is shown. I'm not even getting my 'else' statement.

Any ideas?

MAYBE SOLVED
I may have got the correct way of doing it with:

```html
$sql = "SELECT sum(CASE WHEN member_id = '$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]' AND exercise != 'Personal Training' AND date >= '$mon' THEN mins ELSE 0 END) AS mins FROM completed_activity";
```

Can anyone confirm if this looks right?

Comment: sidenote: dont forget to use an alias `SUM(mins) AS whatever` so that it'll be easier to access it as an index in the array as `$array['whatever']` instead of using `$array['sum(mins)']` and as usual turn on the error reporting, stop guessing and check the error messages

Comment: Ok I did this, but still no luck. When there is nothing, it isn't directing me to my 'else' statement. I am getting $mins = ""; and still schooling 'yes'. Even when there are no records with the WHERE conditions???

Comment: don't use date as column name

Comment: I need to use date as a column name! mysql_num_rows instant working either. I'm getting 'no' when it should be a yes with that...

Comment: Please provide table structure so we can test here

Comment: date being a keyword, add the single ticks around the date in the query
`date` 

write both the sql statements here what you are trying to execute with without date...

Comment: Remember to use `having` when using aggregate functions.

Comment: nope 'date' didn't work.. It just selected all the values.... It works when I have a value between the dates but when I don't, I still get a row, but sum is giving me a value of ""

Comment: I think I solved it with: $sql = "SELECT sum(CASE WHEN member_id = '$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]' AND exercise != 'Personal Training' AND date >= '$mon' THEN mins ELSE 0 END) AS mins FROM completed_activity";


$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$mins = $row["mins"];
echo "yes";
}
} else {
$mins = 0;
echo "no";
}. This still gives me a YES but it gives me the correct sum(). ???

Comment: @TaylorMadePT, as an aside, your SQL statement is a potential security risk.  Please use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @TaylorMadePT, count the rows with this query: SELECT sum(mins) AS mins_sum FROM completed_activity WHERE member_id = '$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]' AND exercise != 'Personal Training'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `SUM`, there are at least one result returned. The result of `SUM` may be 0 or more.

That's why your code is not working correctly.

Try the following code:

```
// connect for other mins
$sql = "SELECT sum(mins) AS mins_sum FROM completed_activity WHERE member_id = '$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]' AND exercise != 'Personal Training' AND date >= '$mon'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mins = $row["mins_sum"];
    if ($mins > 0) {
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer should be implementing a prepared statement for stability/security.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know php code, But When No condition matched sql query will return 0.

Means There will be atleast 1 record. So your if condition will always true.

Improve condition to check for value like

```
if ($result['sum'] > 0) { //Check for syntax
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$mins = $row["mins"];
echo "yes";
}
} else {
$mins = 0;
echo "no";
}
```